# Google Maps SDK for iOS crash after publishing to App Store

Tags: ios, google-maps, crash, publish, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have Goole Map (v1.5) integrated in my iOS App and it works fine when I test it on a real device (iPad 4 iOS 6.1) in Debug mode.

I published my App and when users open the map the application crashes.

I cannot figure where the problem is and why does it crash.

### **Edit:**

Crash Report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Crashed Thread:  0


Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                0x366333e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158

1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x33b6695e objc_exception_throw + 26

2   CoreFoundation                0x36636dbc +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180

3   CoreFoundation                0x36635648 ___forwarding___ + 388

4   CoreFoundation                0x3658d204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20

5   myApp                        0x00053286 -[ELocation loadView] (ELocation.m:45)

6   UIKit                         0x309eb414 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 64

7   UIKit                         0x30a65f7c -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 80

8   UIKit                         0x30a65f22 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 26

9   UIKit                         0x30a100a8 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 292

10  UIKit                         0x30b0569c -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 268

11  UIKit                         0x30ab703a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66

12  UIKit                         0x30ab6fee -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26

13  UIKit                         0x30b05564 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 380

14  UIKit                         0x30ab703a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66

15  UIKit                         0x30ab6fee -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26

16  UIKit                         0x30ab6fc8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40

17  UIKit                         0x30ab687e -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498

18  UIKit                         0x30ab703a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66

19  UIKit                         0x30ab6fee -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26

20  UIKit                         0x30ab6fc8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40

21  UIKit                         0x30ab687e -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498

22  UIKit                         0x30ab6d6c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484

23  UIKit                         0x309df5bc -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520

24  UIKit                         0x309cc8a4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376

25  UIKit                         0x309cc1b2 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194

26  GraphicsServices              0x365465f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586

27  GraphicsServices              0x36546222 PurpleEventCallback + 30

28  CoreFoundation                0x366083e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30

29  CoreFoundation                0x36608386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134

30  CoreFoundation                0x3660720a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378

31  CoreFoundation                0x3657a238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352

32  CoreFoundation                0x3657a0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100

33  GraphicsServices              0x36545336 GSEventRunModal + 70

34  UIKit                         0x30a20284 UIApplicationMain + 1116

35  myApp                        0x0001277e main (main.m:16)

36  myApp                        0x00012734 start + 36



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e32350 __pthread_kill + 8

1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x376aefb2 pthread_kill + 54

2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x376eb366 abort + 90

3   libc++abi.dylib               0x3144cdda abort_message + 70

4   libc++abi.dylib               0x3144a094 default_terminate() + 20

5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x33b66a58 _objc_terminate() + 144

6   libc++abi.dylib               0x3144a118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76

7   libc++abi.dylib               0x3144a1b0 std::terminate() + 16

8   libc++abi.dylib               0x3144b626 __cxa_rethrow + 90

9   libobjc.A.dylib               0x33b669b0 objc_exception_rethrow + 8

10  CoreFoundation                0x3657a29c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452

11  CoreFoundation                0x3657a0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100

12  GraphicsServices              0x36545336 GSEventRunModal + 70

13  UIKit                         0x30a20284 UIApplicationMain + 1116

14  myApp                        0x0001277e main (main.m:16)

15  myApp                        0x00012734 start + 36


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e225d0 kevent64 + 24

1   libdispatch.dylib             0x366c9d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806

2   libdispatch.dylib             0x366c5374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32


Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e32d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8

1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x37686ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14

2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x376867f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362

3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x37686680 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 3 name:  WebThread

Thread 3:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e21e30 mach_msg_trap + 20

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e21fd0 mach_msg + 48

2   CoreFoundation                0x366082b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126

3   CoreFoundation                0x3660702c __CFRunLoopRun + 900

4   CoreFoundation                0x3657a238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352

5   CoreFoundation                0x3657a0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100

6   WebCore                       0x3898aa58 RunWebThread(void*) + 440

7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x376910de _pthread_start + 306

8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x37690fa4 thread_start + 4


Thread 4:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e32d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8

1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x37686ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14

2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x376867f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362

3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x37686680 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1d8a3f90.events

Thread 5:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x33e21e98 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8

1   libdispatch.dylib             0x366c8c16 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 118

2   CoreLocation                  0x32b3a774 CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent, objc_object*) + 340

3   CoreLocation                  0x32b3ddd8 ___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0 + 384

4   CoreLocation                  0x32b740b8 __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 344

5   libxpc.dylib                  0x32457804 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 768

6   libdispatch.dylib             0x366ca688 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 120

7   libdispatch.dylib             0x366c7afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78

8   libdispatch.dylib             0x366ca92e _dispatch_mach_invoke + 166

9   libdispatch.dylib             0x366c7afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78

10  libdispatch.dylib             0x366c5678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40

11  libdispatch.dylib             0x366c7afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78

12  libdispatch.dylib             0x366c5678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40

13  libdispatch.dylib             0x366c8610 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 208

14  libdispatch.dylib             0x366c87d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88

15  libsystem_c.dylib             0x376867ee _pthread_wqthread + 358

16  libsystem_c.dylib             0x37686680 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):

    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3ae97524

    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ae97b78      r6: 0x1cdb5a24      r7: 0x2fdf0a34

    r8: 0x1cdb5a00    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00212bc4

    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdf0a28      lr: 0x376aefb7      pc: 0x33e32350

  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

### **ELocation.m loadView :**

```
- (void)loadView {

    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    _locationManager.delegate = self;

    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    _destLocation = nil;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude zoom:12]; //**line 45**

    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = YES;

    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    mapView.delegate = self;

    self.view = mapView;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading it from the App Store yourself and tested it and grabbed the stacktrace?

Comment: Have you changed the debug API Key to a release one?

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell yes I did .. please check my edited question.

Comment: @TussLászló Is there a release API Key for iOS? I followed the Google documentation and theres nothing written about a release API Key

Answer (score 1):

When you call `[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` then you will receive a callback via `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` when a location is available, asynchronously at some later point. Until then `_locationManager.location` may be nil - although it might not be if your app has previously cached a location.

This *might* be the cause of your crash for users who've not run the app before, as on line 45 you're assuming you have a valid location to create the camera position at. Although I'm not sure, since calling `.coordinate.latitude` on nil should just return 0 instead of crashing.

It may be that your users are being prompted for access to their location, and that attempting to access the location before they've answered yes is what is causing the crash. To reproduce that on your own device you'll need to reset your location & privacy settings. Do this via Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy. Unfortunately this resets it for all of your apps and for all of your privacy options (ie location, photos, contacts, etc). Even if you delete and then reinstall your app, iOS will remember that you've previously answered yes. An easier way might be to try temporarily changing your bundle ID, but then you'll also need to get a new Google maps key.

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve my problem it looks like I forgot to add the CoreLocation.framework to my project although I don't know why it worked without it in debug mode on both device an simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this SDK is iOS 6.0 and greater.  Could the crashes be on older iOS devices?

Comment: Yes I'm aware and my deplyment target is iOS 6.0. I tested on iOS 6 and 7 and still crashes